# partialSum in haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I need to compute the partial sums of a list in haskell. Any ideas of how can I do that?

if I have

```
partialSum (1:3:5:[]) => (1:4:9:[])
partialSum [] => []
partialSum (from 1) => 1:3:6:10:...
```

Comment: What did you try and what problems are you facing ?

Comment: How about: `partialSum xs = scanl (+) 0 xs`? or maybe drop the first element (which will always be 0)

Comment: You last case seems strange...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
partialSum :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
partialSum = drop 1 . scanl (+) 0

λ> take 10 $ partialSum [1..]
[1,3,6,10,15,21,28,36,45,55]
```

**EDIT:** OP requested a version without `scanl`:

```
partialSum :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
partialSum (x:xs) = x : map (+ x) (partialSum xs)
partialSum []     = []
```

Comment: You don't need the `drop`, use `scanl1 (+)`.

Comment: What if I can't use scanl? I need a method without scanl

Comment: `parts [] = []; parts (x:xs) = x:g x xs where { g x [] = []; g x (y:ys) = let z=x+y in z:g z ys }`. Also, `parts xs = snd $ Data.List.mapAccumL (\a x-> (a+x,a+x)) 0 xs`.